# Accessibility Events

Tags: java, android, events, accessibility, accessibilityservice

Which accessibility event should I use to get music player notification?
I am able to get all notification using `AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED`, but music player notification is not detected.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_ANNOUNCEMENT` to know about incoming notifications. Most music players when starting a song, send a notification. This event type could be used to detect a new notification and then use:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.isMusicActive();
```

See: [TYPE_ANNOUNCEMENT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityEvent#TYPE_ANNOUNCEMENT)